# Combining a multiple strings and arrays to one dataProvider for a spark List

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, builder, flex-spark

I'm struggling with this one, what I need to do is combine 5 arrays with 5 individual strings (which have come from a JSON webservice) into one single list item in FlashBuilder Burrito.

The web service returns data as follows

```
Title(String)
Array[0[name, size, imageurl]][1[name, size, imageurl]][2[name, size, imageurl]]

Title_1(String)
Array_1[0[name, size, imageurl]][1[name, size, imageurl]][2[name, size, imageurl]]

Title_2(String)
Array_2[0[name, size, imageurl]][1[name, size, imageurl]][2[name, size, imageurl]]

Title_3(String)
Array_3[0[name, size, imageurl]][1[name, size, imageurl]][2[name, size, imageurl]]
```

And so on. I've pulled these out successfully and each one traces in the debugger, although as I need them all in the same list I'm struggling to establish them as a dataprovider together.

If I push the strings and arrays together it is impossible to read properly, as the main Titles are at a different level to any descriptors for the products which are in the arrays. So I'm sort of stuck!!

Any advice on how best to approach this?

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Really depends on the design of the application on how to best approach this. If the list is going to be sortable on the properties (Name, Size, Price etc) then instead of labels you might want to push the "type" into the array and have a way of showing this in the item renderer. If the items are supposed to be separated by type, but also sortable you might want to look at using an accordion type control and having separate lists.

Anyhow what you want to do is concatenate the arrays into a single array and push the "Title" into the object as a property. This way you can at least sort on the title so the items appear in the correct order in the single list.

Otherwise you could just create a custom control with 5 different lists stacked on top of each other (With no scrollbars) and have the custom control handle scrolling of all 5 lists with a single scroll bar.

Comment: I think this is slightly over my head! How would the code work for this? I did have everything concatenated into an array, although it seemed unreadable to create a list!